# AnaCross: A crossword made of anagrams

Tags: word, no-computers, english, anagram, crosswords

This is a new type of puzzle I've devised: the AnaCross. Nothing new under the sun and all, I'm sure someone has made one before, but I've never seen it.

The rules are pretty simple. At the end of each row is a pool of letters; those letters are the letters that go in that row of the crossword. Normal crossword rules apply, so every line of letters makes a real, English word; there are no proper nouns in the puzzle. All words can be found in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/).

There is, in many cases, more than one word that fits any given row, but there should only be one arrangement that completes every word.

For example, the first row contains a four letter word going across plus the first letter of two other words going down, and those six letters are some arrangement of "CGLOOS".

[image]

Note the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag: the use of anagram solvers is highly discouraged.

Comment: This bears some resemblance to Puzzler's 'Jolly Mixtures' style crosswords, although there they give you the anagram of each individual answer rather than a whole row. They also do an 'Outsider' puzzle, where they list the row letters and the column letters but provide no blanks and just a list of clues in no particular order - as crosswords go, it's one of my favourite types. Worth a look if you live somewhere that you can buy the magazine! :)

Comment: all are words? no abbreviations?

Comment: @SteveV I used no abbreviations.

Comment: Is the word going down at the bottom of column 9 technically a suffix rather than a word in its own right? (If so, I have a full solution - if not, then it's back to dealing with those pesky bottom 2 rows yet again...)

Comment: @Stiv It is a proper word.

Comment: @qwertyu63 Are you saying there are proper words in the grid? How "every line of letters makes a real, English word; there are no proper nouns" should be understood then? There are no proper words on *lines* but there may be proper words in *columns*?

Comment: @xhienne There's no clever trick in my wording; there are no proper nouns in the puzzle at all. In my prior comment, I meant a "proper word" as "not an affix or abbreviation".

Comment: ok, is one of them _two_ words?  if not, then i, um, am giving up.  maybe.

Comment: @SteveV Normal crossword rules apply: each line of letters makes a valid English word. None of them are two words. I'm going to add a clarification to the text.

Comment: Can you double check the last three rows to make sure there isn't a typo in one of the lines?

Comment: @Steve On close examination, it appears you are correct: row 11 should read AABLV. I will correct this when I get home this evening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is one solution with the modified 11th row

> [image]

I think there are be other valid solutions, but they would use archaic/obsolete words.

Comment: Correct on all counts. Well done.

Comment: This is the exact same solution I also had, up to that typo in the puzzle. For ages I could only think the OP had used '[-IUM](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ium)', PRAM and SAY (hence my comment on the main post about suffixes).

Comment: Ditto here, more or less. Almost asked OP to send the sln so I could check it. This is far more expected than the crazy words I was forcing in!

Comment: @Stiv My apologies regarding that. I should have checked that row a third time before publication.

Comment: Having also worked on this for quite a bit, a lot of it looks familiar. I found that with the original letters the only way I could get the bottom three lines to work was by subbing SKI DIVAS with VIA SKIDS but matching this upwards is very very difficult (probably impossible).

Comment: @stiv i was at the "I, um" roadblock too, hoping i could use two words.  i ended up just trying to solve the last three lines by themselves and got nowhere, so was hoping for a typo