# AnaCross II: it's bigger now

Tags: word, no-computers, anagram, crosswords

So, I've prepared another [AnaCross](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107726/anacross-a-crossword-made-of-anagrams) puzzle. The rules are exactly the same: At the end of each row is a pool of letters; those letters are the letters that go in that row of the crossword. Normal crossword rules apply, so every line of letters makes a real, English word; there are no proper nouns in the puzzle. All words can be found in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/).

There is, in many cases, more than one word that fits any given row, but there should only be one arrangement that completes every word.

[image]

Hint: *This hint tells you one word in the grid to serve as a starting point.*

> The word running horizontal in row 7 is "denied".

Comment: This seems... um... incredibly difficult. Props to you if the solution's truly unique, and props to whoever ends up solving this without cheating.

Comment: Some feedback - this is incredibly difficult to do with any hint of being on the right track (believe me - I have tried it). Especially as it's possible to create an almost-correct solution only for it to fail right at the end. One thing that makes it near impossible is that there are so many vowels - using more consonant-heavy words will enable your puzzlers to restrict their possibilities and make it more likely to be solved. Also, perhaps consider having a hidden theme, e.g. include all 12 months among the words, or the 12 signs of the Zodiac - this would give us a useful anchor point :)

Comment: Maybe there _is_ a hidden theme! It's hard to know without having solved the puzzle. (I have tried it _a bit_ and agree that it seems likely very difficult.)

Comment: I can say there is no hidden theme. Perhaps if I make another, there will be, but I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my grid. Unfortunately I didn't capture any mid-process, and used some online word search tools.

> [image]
>
>
>  There are at least three different solutions. We can fill the empty cells on the third-from-the-bottom row with DEAL-ARE, READ-ALE or DEAR-ALE.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is a great first answer. Why don't you finish registering your account - that way you can keep ownership of this answer (which lets you edit it easier, etc.) even if you lose your cookie. The [tour] and [help] are some resources about how this site works. Feel free to look around the site for other puzzles to solve, or set one yourself!

Comment: Of course there's a shuffable line. *sigh* If anyone cares, the 'canon' answer puts DEAL on that line. Well done.